# Android: EditText setError styling background

Tags: android, android-edittext

So I know there's a way to style the setError font color (and a lot of questions / answers about how to do this) using a spannableString but it seems that it's impossible to change the actual background without extending the EditText widget?

I know right now that it's a background image, but I have a replacement drawable for the background I'd like to use.

If it's the case where you have to override, can someone recommend a library to do it?

Comment: The main thing I forgot (maybe it's possible with a theme change) is to use a white background instead of the current black background for edit text errors.